# Does kafka consumer get blocked if message at head of queue is not acknowledged?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Say that I have a kafka cluster where one partition is shared by multiple topics. Each topic has a consumer, say consumer1 for topic1, consumer2 for topic2.
Consider a partition P1, where it has m1 that belongs to topic1 and m2 that belongs to topic2. m1 was produced before m2.
Say that c1 tries to consume m1 but fails. So c1 does not acknowledge m1. Now c2 tries to consume m2, when c2 asks kafka for messages from topic2, will kafka return m2? Or because m1 is at the head, and not ack'ed yet, will Kafka block c2?

Comment: Each partition belongs to exactly one topic, partitions couldn't be shared

Answer (score 2):

> one partition is shared by multiple topics

That's not possible. A producer could send data to multiple topics/partitions at once, but this is duplicated, *distinct* data. It is not shared.

> m1 that belongs to topic1 and m2 that belongs to topic2. m1 was produced before m2

Order is only relevant within a partition of a single topic, not across topics.

---

With these two points in mind, "c1" and "c2" are completely decoupled without additional logic in your own consumer code that is unrelated to Kafka or base Consumer client API, therefore would not block / ack one-another on their own.

If both consumers have the same `group.id` config, then they would "block" each other on all messages in *one partition* since that partition cannot be consumed from more than one consumer at a time.

"Ack-ing" in consumers (committing of offsets) is completely optional, and doesn't determine delivery of records.

If a producer does not flush its buffer, causing data to be sent to the "head of the topic", then that is not "blocking" a consumer since the broker itself didn't get data for the consumer to even poll.